# Сравнить списки по индексам

Tags: python, list, проверка

Есть два списка `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` и `b = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6]`.
Требуется сверить списки по индексам. То есть, проверить `a[0] == b[0]`, потом `a[1] == b[1]`, потом `a[2] == b[2]`, и так далее, до последних элементов `a[i]` и `b[i]`. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `a == b`. Это буквально проверит, что списки равны по длине, и все соответствующие элементы списков равны.

Comment: Может ли различаться длина списков и каков тогда считается результат сравнения?

Comment: @ITexnik Вы ещё про первый свой вопрос не отписались никак, ни один ответ не приняли, что тогда продолжать?

Comment: я только начал пользоваться сайтом. Еще не разобрался ,что да как

Comment: нет длина списков одинаковая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А можно красиво, с помощью `zip`:

```py
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    print(i == j)
```

Вывод:

```py
True
True
False
True
True
True
```

Про `zip` в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Если длина списков разная, `zip` этого не заметит. Но по постановке задачи непонятно, может ли быть такое и что делать в этом случае.

Comment: @CrazyElf для этого есть [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего примера подойдёт:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(a[i] == b[i])
```

Вывод:

```
True
True
False
True
True
True
```

Но если подразумевается, что списки могут быть разной длины, то следует добавить исключение, чтобы не получить ошибку:

```
for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
    try:
        print(a[i] == b[i])
    except IndexError:
        print('один из списков закончился')
```

Comment: а если вместо max использовать min, то можно спокойно обойтись и без исключений

Answer (score 0):

zip обработает количество элементов (точнее пар элементов), равное длине самого короткого списка. Если нужно обработать все элементы самого длинного списка, то используем zip_longest из пакета itertools. Например:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)))
```

Параметр "fillvalue" задает значение по умолчанию, которое будет подставлено в короткий список на место недостающих элементов. Вместо просто "0" можно задать формулу или выражение. Например:

```
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=max(a)))
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=min[a])))
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=a[0])))
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=a[-1])))
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=sum(a)/len(a))))
print(list(x == y for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue= a[-1] if len(a) < len(b) else b[-1])))
print(list(((b[i] if x is None else a[i]) == y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue = None))))
```

Дальше насколько фантазии хватит.